# is there a jackson listener akin to jaxb's Unmarshaller.Listener?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

Does Jackson provide a listener to intercept de-serialization?  The object being serialized and de-serialized contains some standard objects that are stored in MySql.  Rather than creating redundant info, i wish to simply write the code/id of the object during serialization and load the object through a look up during de-serialization.

I currently do it in xml through Jaxb and extending Unmarshaller.Listener.  I am migrating this piece from xml/jaxb to json/jackson.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be interested in the JSON support we've added to EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).  This would give you access to the same mechanisms you've been using for XML: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965201/customize-jackson-objectmapper-to-read-custom-annotation-and-mask-fields-annotat for possible alternative