# Encrypting selected properties while serializing POJOs

Tags: java, json, reflection, jackson, annotations

I am using Jackson to serialize POJOs to JSON before saving them to the database. **For security reasons, I need to encrypt properties marked with the annotation, @Confidential.** The fields (properties) that need to be encrypted **need not be top-level fields and could be deeply nested.**

For example, consider the following POJOs. **homeAddress** and **age** of the person need to be encrypted (they are not the top-level fields of the Neighborhood class).

```
@Serializable 
private class Neighborhood {
   private String name;
   private Collection<Person> people;
}

@Serializable
public class Person {
   private String name;

   @Confidential
   private int age;

   @Confidential
   private Address homeAddress;
}

@Serializable
public class Address {
   private String streetAddress;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private int zip;
}
```

I am thinking of writing an annotation processor that creates a field registry. The registry will be created using reflection and will walk all classes marked with @Serializable annotation. The registry will have information about which fields need to be encrypted and which need not.

Now, after the Neighborhood POJO is serialized to JSON, I should be able to walk to the JSON and look up the fields in the field registry and do the needful. However, I do not know what to do if the properties are collections (i.e. Lists and Maps) and the generic type information is lost.

Questions:

- Is there a better and simpler approach than the one that I described?
  If yes, what's that approach?
- If there isn't a better approach, how do I process collections (lists
  and maps).

This question is not same as [Customize Jackson ObjectMapper to Read custom Annotation and mask fields annotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965201/)

Here are the reason's why:

- We do not know which classes and fields will be annotated with the
  @Confidential annotation. So not sure how I can generate all needed
  custom serializers on the fly and register them with a
  SerializationModule in Jackson's ObjectMapper.
- The generated Serializer should know how to handle both encrypted and non-encrypted fields.
- Not sure how I will inject the Encryption Client in to the
  Serializer.

Comment: Do you really need to `encrypt` them? Maybe easier would be do not include them to output `JSON` using [view](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)? What do you think? In other case, how you would like to encrypt age which is int type? In class this is `int` but in `JSON` it should be `String` does not it?

Comment: Sorry, I do need to encrypt the fields marked as @Confidential. Not including them is not an option.

Comment: I understand. Does link to duplicated question help somehow? If not, we can extend linked solution to handle properly other types then `String`.

Comment: The linked solution does not work for the cases where we don't know which classes and fields are marked as confidential. I modeled something based on https://github.com/codesqueak/jackson-json-crypto but ran into issues when the POJO fields are marked final. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086246