# Jackson's BeanDeserializerModifier does not work with final fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, annotations, lombok

I wrote a Custom Serializer and Custom Deserializer to serialize properties marked with @Confidential annotation.

```
@Data
public class Person {
   private String name;

   @Confidential
   private String address;
}
```

The Custom Serializer serializes a POJO with following values:

```
{ "name": "John Doe", "address": "Kearney St"}
```

as follows:

```
{"name":"John Doe", "address": {"value":"IjIwMzEwIDU4dGggTG4gTkUi"}}
```

The Custom Deserializer is also able to deserialize the JSON back to the Person POJO fine.

**However, when I make the fields in the Person POJO final**, serialization continues to work, **but deserialization fails.**

```
@Data
public class Person {
    private final String name;

    @Confidential
    private final String address;
 }
```

Here's the BeanSerializerModifier implementation:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public BeanDeserializerBuilder updateBuilder(final DeserializationConfig config,
                                                 final BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                 final BeanDeserializerBuilder builder) {
        Iterator<SettableBeanProperty> beanPropertyIterator = builder.getProperties();
        beanPropertyIterator.forEachRemaining(settableBeanProperty -> {
            final Confidential annotation = settableBeanProperty.getAnnotation(Confidential.class);
            if (encryptedProperty != null) {
                JsonDeserializer<Object> current = settableBeanProperty.getValueDeserializer();
                final SettableBeanProperty newSettableBeanProperty =
                        settableBeanProperty.withValueDeserializer(
                                new CustomDeserializer(annotation, current, objectMapper)
                        );
                builder.addOrReplaceProperty(newSettableBeanProperty, true);
            }
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

**I found that CustomDeserializer, never gets called when the Person POJO fields are final.**

Here's the error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: {"name":"John Doe","address":{"value":"IjIwMzEwIDU4dGggTG4gTkUi"}}; line: 1, column: 30] (through reference chain: com.custom.model.Person["address"])
```

**Can a Jackson expert please tell me why my CustomDeserializer isn't getting invoked when the POJO fields are final.**

Thank you!

Comment: Just a quick guess: The problem could be due to the lack of a default constructor. Could you try adding `@NoArgsConstructor` to `Person`?

Comment: Sorry, that is not an option, Jan. We cannot make the class mutable. All the fields need to be final.

Comment: That was not a solution suggestion, just a step to get clearer what the problem is.

Comment: If you use Lombok >= 1.16.20, you could also try adding `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true` to your lombok.config.

Comment: No Jackson experts to respond to the question asked more than 2 years ago?
I face the same issue and would be very interested to know if there is a solution to this issue? Either by using the bean modifier or something else.

Issue is the same with or without Lombok. Any help or feedback is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, serialization will perfectly work for both mutable and immutable fields. Deserialization issue will only occur when using immutable fields as the BeanDeserializerModifier won't work in such a case.

In the Jackson terminology, immutable fields are named creator properties, meaning they are initialized using creators. See BeanDeserializerBase#resolve.

To correctly handle this use case, the ObjectMapper may be created with a custom DeserializationContext (an extended implementation of the ObjectMapper may also set the protected field related to the deserialization context).

Then, through an override of the method DeserializationContext#handleSecondaryContextualization, it will be possible to change the deserialization to make it work.

There is maybe other possibilities but this one is working fine with encryption.